# How to implement a login with Node.js (behind nginx) and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, nginx, passport.js

At the moment I try to build a site with public and private area. I use Node.js server-side. Node.js mainly provides data via REST Web Services for the front-end and handle the login. All data will be stored in a MongoDB. The front-end is built with AngularJS. At the moment I use nginx for static files and only REST calls (/api/…) and the login (/login) will be pass to node.js.

This is my current file structure:

```
www
|-- public
|     |-- css
|     |-- img
|     |-- js
|     |   +-- templates
|     |         +-- login.html 
|     |
|     +-- index.html
|
|-- private
|     |-- css
|     |-- img
|     |-- js
|     |   +-- templates
|     |         +-- someprivatestuff.html 
|     |
|     +-- index.html
```

In Node.js I use passport for authentication.

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('http://localhost/private');
});
```

If the user authed successfully, he will be redirected to /private. The problem is that the file structure above, will be served by the nginx. Because they are static files. How can I prevent people from accessing the private-area directly by typing the url /private (or other files in that directory).  Should I use node.js also for the static files to handle the access to the files?  But I read to use nginx in front of Node.js is a common approach.

Comment: nginx in front is common, but until you have the issues it solves, imho it's best to simply use node.js.

Comment: i readed that node.js is realy bad at serving static files. Is there no other solution?

Comment: Is it possible, that all url calls on /private will first checked by node.js if the user logged in. if its true, the static files will be served by nginx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly this is what you're looking for?

http://wiki.nginx.org/XSendfile

Comment: Please add more information, or a breve summary of what is on the link, link only answers are generally frowned upon